# HTML <img> tag: strange case-sensitivity phenomenon

Tags: html, firefox, case-sensitive

I built a website offline, then put it online. It worked on Chrome, but not on Firefox.

After inspection in Firefox I found the culprit: I linked to an image with a .JPG extension (in the HTML), but the actual file had a .jpg extension. I fixed the error and everything was fine.

So far so good. But the weird thing is: when I had tested the website OFFLINE in Firefox, it worked. In other words: the case sensitivity is required online, but not offline.

Does this make sense? Is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: It is normal. Windows is case insensitive. All other servers are case sensitive

Comment: Your computer runs Windows and the server runs Linux. Most likely explanation.

Comment: But it worked offline in Chrome. So it must be related to the browser too, no?